# Examples of unital non-associative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

What is an example of a unital non-associative algebra?

Comment: The [octonions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505697/examples-of-non-associative-algebras-with-non-associative-division-and-with-un)

Comment: If you pick at random the structure constants of an algebra with probability one you will get  a non associative algebra. Then you add a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some [Jordan algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra) are a good example:

$$a\circ b = \frac{a b + b a}{2}$$
starting from an associative algebra $(A, \cdot)$ with unit $1$.

Note: Jordan was interested in an operation on hermitian operators. So start with $(A, \circ)$ where say $A = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and then $\mathcal{H}$ the hermitian matrices are a Jordan subalgebra.

Answer (score 2):

A pre-Lie algebra structure on $\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C)$ is given as follows, for an arbitrary $a\in \Bbb C$,
\begin{align*}
y_1\cdot y_2 & = \frac{a+1}{2}y_3+\frac{1}{2}y_4,      & y_2\cdot y_4 & =(1-a)y_2,   & y_4\cdot y_1 & =(a+1)y_1,\\
y_1\cdot y_3 & = -y_1,      & y_3\cdot y_1 & =y_1,     & y_4\cdot y_2 & =(1-a)y_2,\\
y_1\cdot y_4 & = (a+1)y_1,  & y_3\cdot y_2 & =-y_2,   & y_4\cdot y_3  & =(1-a^2)y_3-ay_4,\\
y_2\cdot y_1 & = \frac{a-1}{2}y_3+\frac{1}{2}y_4,      & y_3\cdot y_3 & =ay_3+y_4,   & y_4\cdot y_4 & =a(a^2-1)y_3+(a^2+1)y_4,\\
y_2\cdot y_3 & = y_2,       & y_3\cdot y_4 & =(1-a^2)y_3-ay_4,        &              &
\end{align*}
This $4$-dimensional algebra $(A,\cdot)$ is not associative. Now adjoin a unity element to $A$ to obtain a nonassociative, unital algebra - see [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/25156/25156-pdf.pdf), page $8$ after $(7')$.